Why is Entity Framework saying the objects are attached to different ObjectContext objects?
I have a webforms application running on .NET 4.7.2 where, under certain circumstances, the following code gets called from a UI that has been instantiated in a modal window, and in other circumstances, it is called from the UI in the main window.
The MyClass class is not directly in the aspx.cs code-behind, but is injected as a dependency into the code-behind.
myDbContext is injected into MyClass via dependency injection.
Both are injected using the .AddScoped() method.
When MyMethod is called from the modal window, everything works as expected; but when it is called from the main window, the following error is thrown at
myDbContext.myDbTable.Attach(myObject)


The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects

I don't understand why the exception is thrown when the code is clearly using a single context. Any ideas?
Here is the code:
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{    
    private readonly myDbContext;

    public MyClass(DTSEFContainer context)
    {
        myDbContext = context;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var myObject = myDbContext.myDbTable.Where(a => a.ID == 1234).FirstOrDefault();

        if (myObject != null)
        {
            myObject.Name = name;
            myObject.Updated = DateTime.Now();

            myDbContext.myDbTable.Attach(myObject);
            myDbContext.myDbTable.AddOrUpdate(myObject);    
            myDbContext.SaveChanges();                
        }
    }
}

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Based on Steve Py's answer, I did some further digging and found that, in the legacy code, the database context was being used by multiple classes that were being injected. In the dependency injection code, I changed the registration of the database context from scoped to transient. That fixed the issue.
I also removed the .Attach() statement and changed the myDbContext.myDbTable.AddOrUpdate() to myDbContext.SaveChanges().

These two lines should be removed for a start:
        myDbContext.myDbTable.Attach(myObject);
        myDbContext.myDbTable.AddOrUpdate(myObject);    

When you read an entity from a DbContext, by default it is a tracked entity reference. You can alter values and just call .SaveChanges() against the DbContext and EF will review the changes, creating the appropriate UPDATE statement automatically.
Methods like Update and AddOrUpdate are intended for use with detached entities, cases where data has been loaded and detached from a DbContext, or constructed from values and "trusted" to be a new, or existing record that the DbContext will not already be tracking.
I don't think this specific code you have shown will be the cause of the error, but most likely something else that is occurring prior to the update when triggered in the form vs. the modal dialog. Something is setting a reference to a navigation property to an instance of an entity that is not associated with the Scoped DbContext. Normally with web applications you see something similar with detached references trying to result in an INSERT, but based on the exception you posted it seems that there is a reference being set to something tracked by a different DbContext.
